# Get coordinates of white pixels in order forming a curve

Tags: python, image, image-processing, opencv

I have made an algorithm that gets the coordinates of the `n` degree curve in an image given its parameters(constant coefficients).

Equation of curve is as follows:

```
y = a0.x^0 + a1.x^1 + a2.x^2 + ..... + an-1.x^n-1 + an.x^n
```

(`a0`, `a1`, `a2`,... are given)

The issue is that the coordinates of this curve are not stored in order. They are from minimum x coordinate to maximum x coordinate and for each x, from minimum y coordinate to maximum y coordinate. I wish to have these coordinates in order from the starting of the curve to the end of the curve.

Images below explain the way coordinates are currently stored v/s the way they are expected to be stored.

#### Images below are the pixelated image on the line where each box denotes a pixel.

#### Expected order of coordinates:

[image: Expected order]

#### Current order of coordinates:

[image: Current order]

Can anyone suggest an algorithm to solve this problem. Code in python would be appreciable.

Comment: Can you give an example of data structure? Both of current, and desired expected structure?

Comment: The coordinates of these white pixels are stored in a 2D list of size n*2 where n is the number of pixels in the curve and 2 is for the x and y coordinate of the pixel in the image. 
Eg: [ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], ......, [xn, yn] ]

Comment: Do you want them so be simply re-ordered?

Comment: I want the coordinates of these pixels starting from one end of the curve to the other end. Re-ordering will also to the same job.

Comment: I can only guess what exactly it is. (?) Can you give a small example of input data stucture and output ?

Comment: Giving an exact example with numbers would not be feasible and will be confusing. To clarify the images, the images are the pixelated view of the line(zoomed in). Here each box containing a number is actually a pixel and the numbers are denoting the index of that pixel coordinates in the list(ignoring 0th index). I hope this explanation will help.

Comment: pixels.sort( key = lambda x: (x[0],-x[1]) )  , by providing the key you can control on which levels and how you want to sort. use example or similar and play with order/signs to reorder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217521/discussion-between-rahul-kedia-and-user3184950).

Comment: How are these coordinates found? I would suggest that changing the code that generates the list of points will be the most simple solution. One complication in your data is that sometimes the line is 4-connected, and sometimes it is 8-connected, which makes all standard image-processing algorithms break (see https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/connect.htm).

Comment: @Cris The complication you mentioned is the reason why I was stuck at the problem. But thanks for the idea of looking into the code of generation of these points. I found a way around and solved it.

Comment: If you’ve solved your problem, then please either post an answer below or delete the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sort with the lexicographical ordering "left to right, then ties bottom to top".

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @RahulKedia Lookup "lexicographical comparison".

Comment: An n-th degree polynomial doesn't always go bottom to top, it can decrease as well. This is an overly simplistic solution that works only for this one particular example, but will likely not work for other examples.